# AWS DynamoDB Data Mapper: Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cloud

I'm using the [AWS DynamoDB Data Mapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) as a high level API for managing my database. I'm trying to query a Global Secondary Index, but I'm unable to get beyond this exception.

The GSI is based on a post's scheduled end date in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

When I try to build the query like so:

```
function getQueryPaginator( dataMapper: DataMapper, startKey: { [ key: string ]: any } ): QueryPaginator<Load> {
  const today: Date = new Date();
  const partitionKey: string = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth() + 1}-${today.getDate()}`;

  const queryOptions: QueryOptions = {
    indexName: 'PostingExpiryIndex',
    limit: 25
  };

  return dataMapper.query(
    Load,
    {
      partitionKey: partitionKey
    },
    queryOptions
  ).pages();
}
```

And use it:

```
const paginator: QueryPaginator<Load> = getQueryPaginator( dataMapper, lastEvaluatedKey );

    for await ( const page of paginator ) {
      try {
        const loadsBatch: Array<Load> = [];
        page.forEach( ( load: LoadInterface ) => {
          // do some logic...
          loadsBatch.push( Object.assign( new Load(), load ) );
        } );
        dataMapper.batchPut( loadsBatch );
      } catch ( e ) {
        log.error( `Error occurred while processing expired loads: ${e}` );
        await handleError( e );
      }
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element
>       at Request.extractError (/Users/myworkspace/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)

I am however able to query and fetch values using the AWS Document client's equivalent API:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'loads',
    IndexName: 'PostingExpiryIndex', // optional (if querying an index)
    KeyConditionExpression: 'postingEndDate = :value', // a string representing a constraint on the attribute
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { // a map of substitutions for all attribute values
      ':value': '2018-10-26'
    }
};
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Comment: Hi rawkfist0215, Have you found any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem with scan using data mapper. However I got the result with AWS Document client. Let me know how you resolved this. Thanks in advance.